# CSS: I got different results when checking Media Query in devTools, and on a real device

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a Media Query for my project, trying to adjust my page for different screen sizes using a CSS Grid. When I'm testing in Chrome devTools for a specified resolution everything works fine. But on actual monitor things went south. It seems that the actual device screen resolution is ignored, and only a grid dimension has been taken into account. In my case, the resolution is not FHD (1920x1080p) as it should be, but 1745x851p instead.

I hope someone understands what I'm talking about. I'm hoping for a quick fix from a more experienced developer (I'm a beginner in frontend), but I'll provide my code if necessary of course.

Answer (score 1):

CSS only sees view port dimensions as the site's html. It does not include browser tabs or OS Taskbars

Comment: Is there a way to change that, or something else besides rewriting my complete code?

Comment: If Javascript is an option, you can use: window.screen.height, which returns the screen's height. Width works the same. I think you would be better off to just alter the media queries though.

Comment: I'm working just with HTML and CSS, sorry. But I really appreciate your efforts to solve my issue! :bothThumbsUp: